# Volume by shell method with 4 boundaries

Tags: calculus

0

I'm trying to find the volume using the shell method but it's not adding up. Question: Find the volume generated when the region between the curves is rotated around the x-axis. x=y^3, y=1/x, x=1, y=7.

I'm not sure what region they're asking. It is bounded by 4 equations. I used the formula V= `integration 2pi y. g(y) dy and got 2/3. That was wrong. I'm not able to find out the radius and the height using the Shell method. Is there something I'm missing? I could not figure what the radius or height is. Please help.

Comment: Have you sketched the region?

Comment: Also there has to be another bound on $x$

Comment: @Math Lover, yes I've sketched the graph using Desmos online graphing calculator. The problem is I do not know what region to calculate. It seems there are two functions there x=y^3 and x=1/y, and the two other boundaries of x=1, and y=7.

Comment: @maths Lover there was only one bound of x=1. I understand the limit of integration would be on the y-axis but not sure from where to where. is it from 0 to 7 or 1 to 7?

Comment: $x = \frac{1}{y}$ curve is not mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Math Lover, my bad. It's y=1/x not y=1/3. It is y=1/x. The complete question here below: x=y^3, y=1/3, x=1, and y=7 rotated around x-axis

Comment: Without a lower bound of $x$, say y-axis, the question does not make sense. The region bound to the right of $xy = 1$ is not bound by $x = y^3$ specifically.

Comment: @Math Lover there is no xy=1. The question is complete and correct as typed above

Comment: @Math Lover, what about solving for x in the second function of y=1/x

Comment: You may have typed correctly but the question is not correct. What do you mean there is no $xy = 1$? $y = \frac{1}{x} \implies xy = 1$. Please see graph to the left of $xy = 1$ and to the right of it. Left of it makes sense if there is bound of $x = 0$. Right of it makes $x = y^3$ redundant.